# How to align authors in book title page?

Tags: align, titles

I have the following `\author` declaration in a `book` document:

```
\author{
    Lorem Ipsum \and
    Dolor Sit \and
    Amet Whatever \and
    Bozo Clown \and
    Donald Trump \and
    John Smith \and
    Jack Kerouac
}
```

The result in the title page looks clearly unaligned:
[image]

I would like the names on the left column to be left-aligned; names on the right column to be right-aligned; and names in the center column to be center-aligned. How should I go about that?

Comment: What about vertical alignment? Do you want the three columns to be top aligned like they already are or do you want to centre them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution without redefine `\maketitle` and without considering possible side effects in other parts of the document if you try to reuse `\@author`:

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{books}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\title{}
\author{\tabcolsep1em
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{LCR}
    Lorem~Ipsum  Bozo~Clown &
    Dolor~Sit Donald~Trump  Jack~Kerouac &
    Amet~Whatever John~Smith
\end{tabulary}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```